# How to get identity pool Id for a user in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to obtain the identity pool id for a user in cognito.

I have all the credentials required, (username, pw) as well as my client id, pool id, and identity pool id.

I can do this using a browser using the following code:

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err, resp) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('get creds error', err);
                        alert('get creds error' + err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('get creds success', AWS.config.credentials);

                        // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
                        accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
                        secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
                        sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

                        console.log("in creds.get - accessKeyId: " + accessKeyId);
                        console.log("in creds.get - secretyKey: " + secretAccessKey);
                        console.log("in creds.get - sessionToken: " + sessionToken);
                        // get this Id and push to array
                        console.log('UserID: ', AWS.config.credentials.params.IdentityId);
                        users_identity[username] = AWS.config.credentials.params.IdentityId;
                        cognitoUser.signOut();
                    }
                });
```

, however when I try to obtain it for multiple users I can only obtain it for one. the other's have incorrect identity pool id showing when i call

```
  console.log('UserID: ', AWS.config.credentials.params.IdentityId);
```

is it possible to do this in nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

What you're printing is the **identity id**, not identity pool id. The identity id is a unique identifier for each user given by Cognito. I'm not aware of any getter for the identity pool id in the javascript SDK, however this is a value you configured an input in the initialization of the credentials. It should be possible for you to just keep that value accessible and use it if need be.